# !important not overriding materialize css

Tags: css, materialize

I'm trying to override a default css property that materialize had added to an image. When a user hovers their mouse over it, the cursor becomes a magnifying class. I want the cursor to be a pointer.

this is the code I found when using inspect element:

```
.materialboxed {
    display: block;
    cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;
    cursor: zoom-in;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .4s;
    transition: opacity .4s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

this is the code I'm using to override the cursor in my css file:

```
.cursor:hover{
  cursor: pointer !important; 
}
```

this is the line in the html file I'm adding the class onto:

```
<img src="img/GeoNinja.jpg" alt="" class="responsive-img materialboxed activator cursor">
```

I've cleared my cache and my css file is the last stylesheet in my header to be sourced. What am I missing?

edit:

so this works:

```
div>img.cursor {
  cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

but I don't know why this works and my older method didn't. Does anyone here know why?

Comment: Maybe because you did not find _all_ the places where the cursor property for this element was specified.

Answer (score 0):

The second method is more specific. It is looking for a div immediately followed by an img tag rather than just a .cursor tag.

A specified rule always takes precedence over an inherited rule, even if that inherited rule is !important